# Problems using regex \W to match non-word using sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to replace the variable 'a' in the below string with the word 'apple'.  I am trying to use a regex expression in sed, but I am getting strange results

```
=e+a:0==a[q]("/")?a=k+a:a&&0!=a[q]("?")?0>a[y]("/")[0][q]
```

foo.txt contains the above string.

I thought this might work but no match returns:

```
sed 's/\W(a)/apple/g' foo.txt
```

When I try this

```
sed 's/\W/apple/g' foo.txt
```

I get this output

```
appleeappleaapple0appleappleaappleqappleappleappleappleappleappleappleaapplekappleaappleaappleapple0appleappleaappleqappleappleappleappleappleappleapple0appleaappleyappleappleappleappleappleappleapple0appleappleqapple
```

Why is the \W which should match non-word characters not working correctly?  I am running Ubuntu 12.10 distro.

Comment: Why can't you use `sed 's/a/apple/g'`?

Comment: I'm trying to only replace the variable 'a' in a much larger file.  For example, I do not want to change "var a = foo" to "vappler apple = foo"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\W` does not seem to be relevant to your expression.  Why not just replace `a` with `apple`?

```
$ echo '=e+a:0==a[q]("/")?a=k+a:a&&0!=a[q]("?")?0>a[y]("/")[0][q]' | sed -e 's/a/apple/g'
=e+apple:0==apple[q]("/")?apple=k+apple:apple&&0!=apple[q]("?")?0>apple[y]("/")[0][q]
```

You may (rightly) be concerned that this will replace words like `car` with `cappler`.  In this case, you can do this (on Macs and other BSD systems):

```
$ echo 'a abc la car a' | sed -E -e 's/[[:<:]]a[[:>:]]/apple/g'
apple abc la car apple
```

If you have GNU sed it is as easy as:

```
$ echo 'a abc la car a' | sed -E -e 's/\ba\b/apple/g'
apple abc la car apple
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is

```
sed 's/a\W/apple/g' foo.txt
```

This way you are only choosing the letter "a" followed by a non-character, if that is the way you can identify your "a" variable.

"\W" alone is actually matching correctly, as it is replacing any non-word with the whole word "apple".

Comment: Close, but I don't want to replace the actual non-charcter, only the 'a'.  

`sed 's/\Wa/apple/g' foo.txt`

is closer to what I want to do - match a non-word character and then the 'a' to find the variable.  However I only want to replace the 'a', not the non-word character.